# Collision detection between two PictureBox in a WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two `PictureBox` that are moving on the form. They may collide together. How do I know if they collide?

Should I use their location to do so?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask to learn how to ask questions properly. This question has no code examples, and very little detail. A question with this little effort will be closed quickly.

Comment: @JamesHill I agree that there's not enough meat in this question - some code or more detail for the reasoning behind the problem would be beneficial. But it's an extremely straight forward question. So, can someone explain to me why this is a bad question? If anything it's more likely a duplicate than a bad question.

Comment: @RichardBarker, remember, we're not just trying to help the OP, we're trying to help the programming community at large. For that reason, not following the guidelines found in the *How to Ask* section makes it a bad question -  stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here"
It's super easy to tell what's being asked here and it's real question, just poorly composed. What a mean people down-voting it so much.

It helped me.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `Rectangle.IntersectsWith` method to work out whether they intersect.

```
if (pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds))
{
    //They have collided
}
```